# Repeated string clean up, how to make it more concise

Tags: python, pandas, string

I perform a number of cleanups to a dataframe and I am wondering if there is a another way of achieving the same result in more concise way. I have a number of these operations:

```
df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to try a reboot and test if operational' if 'rebooted' in x else x)
df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to try a reboot and test if operational' if 'reboot' in x else x)
df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to perform a system cleanup' if 'system cleanup' in x else x)
df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to update the bios' if 'bios' in x else x)
df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to update windows' if 'windows updates' in x else x)
df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to restart the laptop' if 'laptop restarted' in x else x)
df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to update the driver' if 'updates driver' in x else x)
```

I was thinking perhaps using a map to make it more concise but thought I would just make a post to see if there are other ideas.

Here is the entire function:

```
def clean_df(df):
    # Clean up any leading and trailing spaces and convert to lowercase
    for col in df[['short_description','details','resolution']]:
        df[col] = df[col].str.strip()
        df[col] = df[col].str.lower()

    # Drop rows where strings are less than or equal to 1
    count = df['resolution'].str.split().str.len() # RT
    df = df[~(count==1)]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    df = df[df['resolution'].str.contains(' ')]
    df = df[df['resolution'].notna()]
    df = df.dropna()

    # Apply regular expression matching to delete urls and pathnames
    df["resolution"].replace(to_replace=r'^https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', value="", 
                    regex=True, inplace=True)
    df["resolution"].replace(to_replace=r'http\S+', value="", 
                    regex=True, inplace=True)
    df["resolution"].replace(to_replace=r'c:\\\S+', value="", 
                    regex=True, inplace=True)
    df["resolution"].replace('-', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
    
    # Remove substrings that contain numbers
    df['resolution'] = df['resolution'].apply(rid_numbers)
    
    df = df[~df['resolution'].str.contains("resolved")]
    df = df[~df['resolution'].str.contains("no reply")]
   

    df['resolution_modified'] = ''
    # Create sentence where string contains content below
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to try a reboot and test if operational' if 'rebooted' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to try a reboot and test if operational' if 'reboot' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to perform a system cleanup' if 'system cleanup' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to update the bios' if 'bios' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to update windows' if 'windows updates' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to restart the laptop' if 'laptop restarted' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to update the driver' if 'updates driver' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to reconfigure the printer' if 'printer reconfigured' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to reconfigure the printer' if 'reconfigured printer' in x else x)
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('reconfigured printer')] = 'It is recommended to reconfigure the printer'
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to reconfigure the printer' if 'printer reconfigured its working now' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to reconfigure the scanner' if 'scanner reconfigured' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to reconfigure the scanner' if 'scanner was reconfigured' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to reconfigure the printer' if 'reconfigured the printer' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to reconfigure the pslip' if 'pslip reconfigured' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to try a reboot' if 'rebooted' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to reimage the laptop' if 'laptop reimaged' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to reimage the laptop' if 'laptop was reimaged' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to reimage the laptop' if 'laptops reimaged' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to reconfigure the scanner' if 'scanner was reconfigured' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to reconfigure the scanner' if 'printer was reconfigured' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to resync the scanner to the station' if 'scanner resynced to station' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to reconnect scanner to base' if 'scanner reconnected to base' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to perform a factory reset' if 'factory resetconfiguredtested' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to uninstall and reinstall printer driver' if 'printer driver uninstalled and reinstalled' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to clean the sensor and reposition the printer' if 'after cleaning the sensor and repositioned the internal sensor the printers started printing normally' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to recalibrate the printer' if 'i recalibrated the printer' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to recalibrate the screen' if 'i recalibrated the screen' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to clean and test to see if operational' if 'clean' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to reconfigure and test to see if operational' if 'reconfigured' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to to send in for repair or replace item' if 'physical damage' in x else x)
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('faulty')] = 'It is recommended to send in for repair or replace item'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('damaged')] = 'It is recommended to send in for repair or replace item'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('broken')] = 'It is recommended to send in for repair or replace item'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('defective')] = 'It is recommended to send in for repair or replace item'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('not working')] = 'It is recommended to send in for repair or replace item'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('replaced printer')] = 'It is recommended to replace the printer'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('reprogrammed')] = 'It is recommended to replace the printer'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('scanner is replaced')] = 'It is recommended to replace the scanner'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('faulty scanner')] = 'It is recommended to replace the scanner'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('scanner is damaged')] = 'It is recommended to replace the scanner'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('replaced the monitor')] = 'It is recommended to replace the monitor'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('cache and cookies')] = 'It is recommended to clear cache and cookies'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('cache')] = 'It is recommended to clear cache and cookies'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('cookies')] = 'It is recommended to clear cache and cookies'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('replaced battery')] = 'It is recommended to replace the battery'
    df['resolution_modified'][df.resolution.str.contains('the printer has been replaced')] = 'It is recommended to replace the battery'
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to send in for repair or replace item' if 'defective' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to make a request for replacement' if 'missing' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to make a request for replacement' if 'scanner was missing' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to make a request for replacement' if 'repair by replacement' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to make a request for replacement' if 'defective printer replaced' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to make a request for replacement' if 'defective printer' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to sync and test to see if operational' if 'not synced' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to try a restart and test to see if operational' if 'works after restart' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to take the plug out and in then test to see if operational' if 'was not plugged in' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to take the plug out and in then test to see if operational' if 'wasnt plugged in' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to replace the printer' if 'replaced printer' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to replace the printer' if 'replaced the printer' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to replace the scanner' if 'replaced a new scanner' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to replace the scanner' if 'replaced scanner' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to replace the scanner' if 'scanner was replaced' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to replace the scanner' if 'scanner is now replaced' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to replace the cable' if 'replaced cable' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to replace the keyboard' if 'keyboard replacement' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to replace the mouse' if 'replaced the mouse' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to replace the mouse' if 'mouse had been replaced' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to replace the mouse' if 'mouse is replaced' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to replace the adapter' if 'adapter replaced' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to replace the power cord' if 'replaced power cord' in x else x)
    df.resolution_modified = df.resolution.apply(lambda x: 'It is recommended to replace cartridge' if 'cartridge need to be replace' in x else x)
    
    # Remove punctuation
    df["resolution"] = df['resolution'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
    
    replacement_dict = {
        're-programmed': 'reprogram',
        'eployed' : 'deployed',
        'scanner replaced': 'replaced scanner',
        'unpluggedplugged': 'unplugged and plugged',
        'printer reconnected': 'It is recommended to reconnect the printer',
        'plug out and plug in' : 'It is recommended to plug in and out again'
    }   
    
        
    df['resolution'] = df['resolution'] .replace(replacement_dict)
    print("Done preprocessing!")
        
    return df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a dictionary with all of the keywords and replacement strings.  The keys would be a regex pattern such as `.*reboot.*` to capture the entire sentence if it has `reboot` in it, and replace with the related key.

```
resolution_map = {
    '.*reboot.*':'It is recommended to try a reboot and test if operational',
    '.*bios.*':'It is recommended to update the bios'
}

df = pd.DataFrame({'resolution':['I did reboot the computer','we updated the bios','mars is a planet']})

df['resolution'].replace(resolution_map, regex=True)
```

Output

```
0    It is recommended to try a reboot and test if ...
1                 It is recommended to update the bios
2                                     mars is a planet
```

Comment: Does order matter in the mapping. Example would I need to do this  ``` '.*printer reconfigured.*' : 'It is recommended to reconfigure the printer',
    '.*reconfigured printer.*' : 'It is recommended to reconfigure the printer',```